# Is there a term for the "auto search" that Google Instant utilizes?

Tags: search, terminology

Is there an official term for the automatic search that Google Instant uses once you stop typing for about 1 second? This is also used on UX.SE when searching for a user. I am looking to add this into a client application and have been searching for information on how to do it in our platform, but can't find much. My guess is that I am not using the right terminology.

**Is there an official term for this type of behavior? (Not the prediction aspect, but the search results being processed without actually clicking search)**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Results as you type](http://www.google.com/support/websearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=186610&topic=1186810) is the term used by Google themselves (which links on to the page about [autocomplete](http://www.google.com/support/websearch/bin/answer.py?answer=106230))

This [SemaText](http://sematext.com/products/autocomplete/index.html) page suggests a collection of terms:

- Search AutoComplete
- Auto-Complete
- Auto-Suggest
- Search suggest
- Suggest as you type
- Read-ahead

[YUI](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/autocomplete/) is an example css and javascript library that has a controllable query delay that you can use to change the delay before a query is activated when the user pauses typing.

Comment: Sorry Roger I wasn't clear in my question, I have edited it now. I am not concerned with the predictive capabilities, but mainly the action of the search being performed without actually clicking search.

Comment: Am I still off track now?

Comment: Nope :) Closer to what I am looking for, I am going to try and see what I can find using those terms. My platform is WPF (XAML + C#). I'll see what I can find now.

Comment: A "WPF AutoComplete TextBox" seems to be the winner. Thanks!