# Is there a name for the pattern of a categorized autocomplete?

Tags: design-patterns, search, terminology, search-results

Lately, I've noticed that Facebook search presents it's autocomplete options as a nice categorized list:

[image: Facebook Search Result]

However, I'm uncertain what to call this pattern. It reminds me a bit of what Peter Morville calls "Federated Search" (in his excellent book *[Search Patterns](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596802288.do)*; [here's a Slideshare overview](http://www.slideshare.net/morville/search-patterns-the-future-of-discovery) of the content and [here's his pattern library](http://www.flickr.com/photos/morville/collections/72157603785835882/)), whereby the search is run simultaneously across multiple databases, and the results are presented in discrete categories by source.

The (now defunct) [Kosmix search result page](http://www.flickr.com/photos/morville/4274338154/in/set-72157623085894897) is an example of this, with results being returned in separated categorized (non-intermingled) panes:

[image: Kosmix Results]

However, "federated search" has typically referred to the *results page pattern*, not something that exists in the auto-complete space.  I've taken to calling this **federated auto-complete**, but I'm wondering if there's another common/"more official" name that exists?

Comment: iOS does this as well in their search page, as dies Windows 7's Start search. Still dunno what it's called.

Comment: @BenBrocka Aren't both of those examples cases of [results as you type](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/13920/is-there-a-term-for-the-auto-search-that-google-instant-utilizes) coupled with a federated display of those results? The unique thing about Facebook for me is that the federated auto-complete is completely separate from the SERP (which is also federated, but returns different results).

Comment: I guess, I figured you were focused more on the category segregation rather than the specifics of autocomplete vs search results. Technically the FB "autocomplete" is also a results page

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This sounds like a composite of two patterns.  It's not a hybrid, borrowing some aspects from autocomplete and some from federated search; it's nothing more or less than auto-complete and federated search used together. Therefore I think your calling out the existing patterns is preferable to using a unique name, even if someone has already coined one.

This is a little nit-picky, but it should be called **federated auto-*suggest***, the difference being that auto-complete is for search *terms* and auto-suggest is for search *results*.

Comment: +1 for **federated auto-suggest** (instead of auto-complete). I always confuse the names of the two patterns.

Comment: Me too, to the point that I edited your question with the intent of changing "complete" to "suggest" and still got it backwards.

Comment: That kind of search is also known as *faceted* search.

Comment: @Agos Federated search presents the results broken up into categories. Faceted search allows the results to be filtered by category.